# Collapse all files in pull request one action bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request

Just a straight forward question, but couldn't find any solution in internet.

Is it possible to collapse all files in a bit bucket PR, in one action? Hot-key or UI button?

[image]

Please help.

Comment: If there is no option provided in bitbucket the the same be achieved by writing javascript code to click on all the collapse (buttons, links or whatever it it) in one line.

Comment: @stud3nt I think there should be one, otherwise its annoying when dealing with large #of files

Comment: Did the solution work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With New Updates (I think), It's supported as following

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this [link](https://github.blog/changelog/2018-08-17-collapse-all-diffs-in-a-pull-request-at-once/), hope this will help!

I don't have access to bitbucekt, otherwise I'd have tested it myself.

**UPDATE 1: Auto Collapse Diffs**

When a pull request contains a lot of changed files, code reviewers can find it hard to isolate the changes that are relevant to them. Now you can collapse (or expand) the contents of all diffs in a pull request by holding down the alt key and clicking on the inverted caret icon in any file header.

**UPDATE 2:**

Click on any of the tilted caret sign `>` (it is highlighted in yellow box, left top corner) while pressing the `Alt` key.[image]

Comment: sorry. I dnt understand wht suggest.

Comment: Did you try clicking on the inverted caret icon `>` while pressing `Alt` key ?

Comment: I dnt understand u, where i should click?

Comment: Please check the updated answer, let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: this doesnt collapse all, only current file. same effect ass just mouse click

Comment: oh ok. I'm looking at this public [repo](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/pull-requests/61/py3-clean-poc/diff) at bitbucket. It does not show the collapse and expand buttons at all. I hope you are using bitbucket web right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202844/discussion-between-stud3nt-and-supun-wijerathne).

Answer (score 0):

For no dark-mode users, in a bitbucket PR, click the popup-menu at the end of the changed file -

[image]